# If/else condition is not working with Python

Tags: python, if-statement

Below is the code - where I'm trying to fetch the file contains specific name if not I need an email to be sent. But in this case, else is always testing true and email has been sent though the file name is correct.

```
for file in test:

    if (file.__contains__("Consolidated Engine run")) and (file.endswith('.xlsx')):
        customer_file = os.path.join(newpath, file)
        print(customer_file)
    else:
        import win32com.client as win32

        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

        mail.To = 'xyz.com'
        mail.Subject = 'Change in the file name or format'
        mail.Send()
        quit()
```

Please guide me as where i'm wrong. I want my else condition not to execute if the file contains "Consolidated Engine run" and is .xlsx format

Comment: `__contains__` doesn't look at the file's contents, it looks at the file's name.

Comment: Can you give an example of `file` where the `if` should be true?

Comment: @AKX, yes i'm looking in the file name.

Comment: @Radhika So you'd need file named `"Consolidated Engine run.xlsx"` for this if to be true.

Comment: @AKX, I'm getting the print of file name. My question is, why again else condition is running. As I got the print, else should not execute

Comment: You're inside a for loop, are you sure the if and else are running against the same file

Comment: test has more than one file? :)

Comment: Also you shouldn't call `__contains__` directly, use the `in` operator like so: `"Consolidated Engine run" in file`

Comment: When customer_file is printed, your code will continue with the next iteration of *test*. The code in the *else* block will **not** be executed

Comment: yes, test has more than one file I think.

Comment: @Radhika: *"test has more than one file I think"* - Time to stop guessing and [start debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  You're essentially asserting that the `if` structure in Python is somehow broken.  It isn't.  Your next step is to step through the code in a debugger and observe the exact values and behaviors of the runtime execution.  When you do this, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @David Thanks. I'll try to debug. I'm new to python and learning and not from any coding background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is from where you put the else block in the loop that loops through the files. Instead of checking every file in your setup, the email is sent for each one that doesn't fit the condition in the if statement because the otherwise block runs for every file that doesn't meet that criterion.

to fix the issues try the code below,

```
import os
import win32com.client as win32

# Assumes 'newpath' and 'test' are defined in your code
found = False
for file in test:
    if "Consolidated Engine run" in file and file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        customer_file = os.path.join(newpath, file)
        print(customer_file)
        found = True
        break

if not found:
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = 'xyz.com'
    mail.Subject = 'Change in the file name or format'
    mail.Send()
```

Comment: Or use `for-else`...